# Check if MongoDB PHP Driver is installed

Tags: php, mongodb, driver

I am developing an install script for my application, how would I go about checking if MongoDB is installed or not with a PHP driver on a server??

Many thanks

Answer (score 17):

The easiest way of checking it would be to run:

```
echo extension_loaded("mongo") ? "loaded\n" : "not loaded\n";
```

See also: http://php.net/manual/en/function.extension-loaded.php

Answer (score 3):

[get_loaded_extensions](http://jp.php.net/manual/en/function.get-loaded-extensions.php) — Returns an array with the names of all modules compiled and loaded.

```
print_r(get_loaded_extensions());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check by using [`class_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php)

```
if (class_exists('Mongo')) {
   // MongoDB is installed
}
else {
   // MongoDB is not installed
}
```

Comment: Mongo is not a function, it's class you can use `class_exists`