# Check MongoDB php driver version

Tags: php, mongodb, unix

I installed the MongoDB PHP driver on my Linux machine a few months ago. Now, I want to know which version of the driver I installed. How can I find this information?

Comment: Use [`phpinfo(8)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php). See http://stackoverflow.com/a/13620634/595525

Answer (score 48):

#### Legacy PECL Extension

The easiest way on the command line is by invoking reflection info:

```
$ php --ri mongo | grep Version
```

will output for example:

```
Version => 1.4.4
```

This will run [ReflectionExtension::info()](http://php.net/reflectionextension.info) on the mongo extension, and grep the Version column.

Couple of other alternatives would be to execute some code, and print out the version information.

The [MongoClient](http://php.net/mongoclient) class (and the Mongo class for old extensions) as a [VERSION](http://php.net/class.mongoclient#mongoclient.constants.version) constant:

```
$ php -r 'echo MongoClient::VERSION, "\n";'
```

will output (for example):

```
1.4.4
```

Or you could use the [phpversion](http://php.net/phpversion) function to retrieve the version number from the module initialization:

```
$ php -r 'echo phpversion("mongo"), "\n";'
```

will output (for example):

```
1.4.4
```

---

#### EDIT - New Extension:

The above refers to the now-old and legacy [pecl/mongo](https://pecl.php.net/package/mongo) extension.
There is a new extension called [pecl/mongodb](https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb).

Similar commands work for the new extension:

```
$ php --ri mongodb | grep version
mongodb version => 1.1.2
libmongoc version => 1.3.1-dev
libbson version => 1.3.0
$ php -r 'echo MONGODB_VERSION, "\n";'
1.2.2
$ php -r 'echo phpversion("mongodb"), "\n";'
1.2.2
$ php -dmongodb.debug=stdout -r 'new MongoDB\Driver\Manager;' | grep Creating
[2016-03-01T17:59:23+00:00]     PHONGO: DEBUG   > Creating Manager, phongo-1.1.2[stable] - mongoc-1.3.1-dev(bundled), libbson-1.3.0(bundled), php-5.6.16
```

Answer (score 8):

Use pecl to check the current local version and the latest version available:

```
pecl search mongo
```

You should see this information:

```
Package Stable/(Latest) Local
mongo   1.x.x (stable)  1.x.x MongoDB database driver
```

Answer (score 6):

For recent versions, the command is `php --ri mongodb`.

Answer (score 3):

Run PHP test and check `MongoDB` section

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```